# why cant I push reverted commit in github?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-checkout, git-revert

I'm pretty new in git.I was working on a project and I used new commit that ruined my project.

so I used git log and git check out to go back to last commit.that was successful on my computer but when I try to push it on github repository I see this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/bamdadghoori/courses.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

bamdad@DESKTOP-MJ4O8KO MINGW64 /e/courses (master)
```

these are some ways I tried

1-reinitializing  and using new commit

2-using git revert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's really what you want to do `git push --force` should do the trick. Be aware that it might erase your old work if you misuse it.

Just like you suggested `git revert` is probably the better option as it does not delete or overwrite any history.
Let's say your branches `git log` looks like this:

```
commit 95c374fca46bee52b9fd18e090e6afdfbe73813d (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
Author: Git User <git.user@mail.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 19 17:02:49 2021 +0100

    Latest commit message

commit 1177cab6490264e922075f28804404f4e1c08f76 (origin/main, main)
Author: Git User <git.user@mail.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 17 12:35:33 2021 +0100

    Commit message of the one you would like to keep
```

If you want to revert the latest commit you can just do `git revert HEAD` (HEAD is always referring to the last commit of your branch) or to revert any commit every you can copy paste the commit hash. In this case `git revert 95c374fca46bee52b9fd18e090e6afdfbe73813d`.
Then accept the suggested commit message which is probably opened in vim by typing `ZZ` (mind the uppercase) or `:wp` and then press Enter.

Comment: tnx.but I tried this way (git revert).it was useful on my local machine.but I can't push it in github and I also worry about using --force or --f pushing. because it causes some problems (for example just like you said erasing work or history)

Comment: try `git pull`ing beforehand you probably still miss the one commit you tried to revert

Comment: tnx @Wischm0pp it works now.there are no errors in git bash when I try to push and I can see last commit (that I reverted) in commits section.but it could be more excellent if I see this version when I open the repository(by default) instead of wrong commit .